# Logging Doctrine queries from Symfony 1.4 tasks

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I'd like Symfony to log the Doctrine SQL queries that one of my tasks executes to a log file, much like the web debug toolbar does for non-cli code. Is this possible?

- Symfony version: 1.4.12
- Doctrine version: 1.2.4

Here's some example code for a task. I would like the SELECT query to be logged in a similar way to how it would be if it was called from an action.

```
class exampleTask extends sfBaseTask
{
        protected function configure()
        {
                parent::configure();

                $this->namespace        = 'test';
                $this->name             = 'example';
        }

        protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
        {
                $databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager($this->configuration);

                $users = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SfGuardUser')
                        ->createQuery('s')
                        ->select('s.first_name')
                        ->execute();

                foreach($users as $user) {
                        print $user->getFirstName()."\n";
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the global task option `--trace` (shortcut `-t`). Like:

```
./symfony --trace namespace:task
```

It logs database queries the moment they are executed.

*Don't forget to enable logging in the settings.yml of the application you're running the task in.*

So if you're running the task in the `dev` environment of the backend you would edit `apps/backend/config/settings.yml`:

```
dev:
  .settings:
    logging_enabled:        true
```

Note that this also logs stack traces of exception which might also be very helpful if you need to debug your tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn logging on all queries should be logged to your application log in the `log` directory. To do this set `logging_enabled` to `true` in your `settings.yml`.

You can then `tail -f` on the logfile and see what's going on.

Comment: Tasks aren't part of the application - there doesn't seem to be a settings.yml which covers tasks.

Comment: @Ian Gregory: Sorry if my answer was not that helpful so far. Can you please specify the doctrine version you're using and your task and it's code within the answer?